# Cucumber step definition folder naming

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I have just started using cucumber and am seeking clarification whether the folder having my step definitions must be named exactly as `step_defnitions` or can it be anything (e.g. `my_defs`).  I tried renaming in my local machine but sometimes it works and sometimes doesn't.

```
features/
|
|-- step_definitions/
```

Comment: would love to help but am not sure what the question is. Are you trying to see if there is a folder inside your current directory? or possibly just checking for a file?

Answer (score 4):

Cucumber will automatically load any files within the features folder. This means that your step definition files can be located in any folder name/structure as long as they are in the features folder.

Note that it is possible to override this setting and explicitly state the location of your steps by doing:

```
cucumber -r your/steps/folder/location
```

For more details you can see the help - `cucumber -h`:

> -r: Require files before executing the features. If this option is not specified, all *.rb files that are siblings or
>   below the features will be loaded auto-matically. Automatic loading is
>   disabled when this option is specified, and all loading becomes
>   explicit. Files under directories named "support" are always loaded
>   first. This option can be specified multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

In every reference I've seen (including the [RSpec Book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book)), they always have a "step_definitions" folder for definitions.  A lot of things in Ruby (and especially Rails) utilize a "convention over configuration" philosophy, and I believe this is one of those things.  I think it'd be less hassle for you to just make the "step_definitions" folder inside the "features" folder and know that it should work than to try and figure out how to change the configuration.